# Authenticating Google Gmail API using access and refresh token

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have searched for an answer to this specifically but can't seem to find it. Apologies if it's a repeat.

I have the access token and the refresh token and want to send the emails using these tokens. The tokens are generated using the passport.js library and I am storing them in the DB along with other profile data. Like this

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CALLBACK_URL,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },(request:any,accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: any)=>{
    //save credentials in database
}));
```

Now using the access token and the refresh token I want to access the Gmail API. Contrary to the example (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) provided by Google. In which they are providing the Oauth client created from executing Oauth2 flow.

What is needed is something like this

```
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth:{accessToken,refreshToken});
```

Comment: Okay your going to need to add the client id and client secrete to  auth:{accessToken,refreshToken}  The library will need them to refresh the token.

Answer (score 1):

**In summary:** Pretty much what DalmTo said in his comment. You need to also add the client ID, secret and redirect URL.

**Explanation:** It may be a little hard to see but the [sample](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_set_up_the_sample) that you provided does show how to authenticate with locally stored information. I'll try to simplify it.

The most relevant parts are under the `authorize()` function:

```js
//first create a google.auth.OAuth2 object
//for this you still have to use your app's client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri

  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
```

The sample app creates a `token.json` file that it uses to reauthenticate. It's just a simple object with the tokens (there are a couple additional fields which I removed since they are not relevant to this):

```js
{
  "access_token":"ya29...",
  "refresh_token":"1//..."
}
```

Then the sample shows that you have to call `setCredentials()` on the `oAuth2Client` object using this token file that was created.

```
oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
```

Then once you have set the credentials to the `oAuth2Client` object you can use it to authorize the API:

```js
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', oAuth2Client});
```

The sample works with a locally stored file, but since you store the tokens in your database in your case it might look more like this:

```js
    //get the tokens from somewhere in your database
    const tokens = {
      "access_token" : ACCESS_TOKEN,
      "refresh_token" : REFRESH_TOKEN
    }

    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
      process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
      process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CALLBACK_URL
    );

    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', oAuth2Client});
```

You'll probably also need to handle reauthorization in case that the refresh token has expired or the user has revoked access but I hope this gives you a general idea.

**More info:** [Google API's Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/gmail/index.html#oauth2-client)